# Using VBA to copy and paste values next empty row

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

Trying to copy from the same line of data in a worksheet and paste values in the next empty row within the set of data.

In the image attached, my code is copying from the bar of gray data at the bottom and would paste those values in the next empty line of data up top

[image: Picture of my worksheet]

In the image attached, my code is copying from the bar of gray data at the bottom and would paste those values in the next empty line of data up top

Here's what I've got - Please help. My question is how to I get it to paste values on the next empty row within the data set

```
    Range("B412:O412").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B390").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("P389:Z389").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("P390").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba

Comment: What if I wanted to perform this same exact function on another sheet within the same workbook, so it would copy from the range specified on the active page and paste values in the selected cell?

Comment: The same linked thread still applies.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy a Range to Another Worksheet

**Final**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyTwoRange()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim srg As Range
    Dim dCell As Range
    
    Set srg = sws.Range("B412:O412")
    Set dCell = dws.Cells(dlRow, "B").Offset(1)
    dCell.Resize(, srg.Columns.Count).Value = srg.Value
    
    Set srg = sws.Range("P389:Z389")
    Set dCell = dws.Cells(dlRow, "P").Offset(1)
    dCell.Resize(, srg.Columns.Count).Value = srg.Value

End Sub
```

**One Range**

```
Sub Lesson()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source (Copy FROM (Read))
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("B412:O412")
    
    ' Destination (Copy TO (Paste, Write))
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    ' Last Row
    Dim dlRow As Long
    
    ' Last non-empty row in column `B` using 'End' (most popular, easy).
    dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
'    ' Last non-empty row in column 'B' using 'Find'.
'    dlRow = dws.Columns("B").Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious).Row
'
'    ' Last NON-BLANK row in column 'B' using 'Find'. Useful when there are
'    ' many formulas evaluating to an empty string ("") at the bottom and
'    ' you want to exclude them.
'    dlRow = dws.Columns("B").Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious).Row
    
    ' With 'Offset(1)', the cell BELOW the last row is referenced.
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Cells(dlRow, "B").Offset(1)
    
    ' Copy
    
    ' Copy ONLY VALUES (copy by assignment)
    dCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count).Value = srg.Value
    
'    ' Copy values and formats and formulas
'    srg.Copy dCell ' short for srg.Copy Destination:=dCell
'
'    ' Copy values and/or formats and/or formulas and/or column widths...
'    srg.Copy
'    dCell.PasteSpecial ' many options
'    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub
```

**Two Ranges**

```
Sub LessonLearned()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("B412:O412")
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Cells(dlRow, "B").Offset(1)
    
    ' Since you are copying only one row, you can use...
    dCell.Resize(, srg.Columns.Count).Value = srg.Value
'    ' ... which is short of...
'    dCell.Resize(1, srg.Columns.Count).Value = srg.Value
'    ' ...instead of ...
'    dCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count).Value = srg.Value
    
    ' Since the results from the first one-row range go into the same row
    ' adjacent to the first range you could do:
    With sws.Range("P389:Z389")
        dCell.Offset(, srg.Columns.Count) _
            .Resize(, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
    ' ... where the columns count of the previous range is used as the offset,
    ' while the columns count of the current range is used with 'Resize'.
    
    ' Of course, this may be too advanced at this moment so you should use...
    
    Set srg = sws.Range("P389:Z389")
    ' If the last rows are different then do:
    'dlRow = dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
    Set dCell = dws.Cells(dlRow, "P").Offset(1)
    dCell.Resize(, srg.Columns.Count).Value = srg.Value

End Sub
```